# Apache Tika parsing from FTP file stream

Tags: java, ftp, apache-tika

I'm using Apache Tika parser to read the contents of a file in a local file system using the below code

```
          ContentHandler textHandler = new BodyContentHandler();
          Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
          ParseContext context = new ParseContext();
          InputStream input = new FileInputStream(file);

          try {
            _autoParser.parse(input, textHandler, metadata, context);
          } catch (Exception e) {

            log(String.format("File %s failed", file.getCanonicalPath()));
            e.printStackTrace();
            continue;
          }

          list.add(textHandler.toString);
```

Now I wanted to get the files from a FTP location, is there any way I could do the parsing on the files in FTP during runtime without downloading them to any location.

Comment: Use a Java FTP client, and parse the `InputStream` from the client straight to Apache Tika?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [Apache Commons Net](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/) library to fetch the InputStream of the FTP file.

**Sample :**

```
    String server = "www.myserver.com";
    int port = 21;
    String user = "user";
    String pass = "pass";

    FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();

    ftpClient.connect(server, port);
    ftpClient.login(user, pass);
    InputStream inputStream = ftpClient.retrieveFileStream("/test/test1.txt");
```